# How to convert escape characters to ANSI from string in XML

Tags: c#, xml, printing

When i use a Windows service written in C# to send a raw string to a receipt printer that uses escape sequences to initiate features within the printer. Such as:

`\x1b\x64\x02`

to operate the paper cutter.

I'm using a receipt template file on another server and placing the text, base 64 encoded, into XML to give it to the Windows service. The problem is that the text is literally printed on the receipt when extracting it from the XML and it's something to do with the escape characters not being translated.

I'm guessing that when i type those escape sequences into Visual Studio, it represents the ANSI character right there in the string (because it works when i do it that way and then the paper cutter triggers).

How would i translate the string containing escape sequences into the proper format for use within the C# Windows service? The goal is to type these simple escape sequences into a template file and then convert them properly on the other end.

C# code i have at the moment that is trying to decode base 64 and then convert to ANSI encoding:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
content = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
content = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(utf8Bytes);

return RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(getConfig().receiptPrinter, content);
```

Here is the content of the test receipt that is received by the service:

`XHgxYlx4MWRceDYxXHgxIE1OSG9tZU91dGxldC5jb20yMzAwIFdlc3QgSGlnaHdheSAxMw0KQnVybnN2aWxsZSwgTU4gNTUzMzcNCjk1Mi0yNzktMTU4Nw0KDQpceDFiXHgxZFx4NjFceDBceDFiXHg0NFx4Mlx4MTBceDIyXHgwIERhdGU6IDIwMTctMDYtMTVceDkgVGltZTogMzo0NmFtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tIA0KXHgxYlx4NDUgU0FMRSANClx4MWJceDQ2`

When i base 64 encode `\x7` for example,

- From within the service: `Bw==` (as ASCII)
- From within the service: `BwA=` (as Unicode)
- From a string in php: `XHg3`

Comment: We need to see some code, ideally a [mcve] showing how the XML is generated.  That being said, `\x1b` and `\x02` are invalid Unicode character codes to include in an XML file according to the [XML Standard 1.0 (fourth edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#charsets) supported by [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).  Thus if you are using `XmlWriter` these characters are probably getting escaped.

Comment: You might also want to use `\uNNNN` character literal format instead of `\xNN` format.  For reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175520/3744182) it's less error-prone.

Comment: I updated the answer. I've since base 64 encoded the content of the receipt to cut XML compliance out of the equation.

Comment: The code above shows how you are decoding a `content` string.  How are you encoding it in the first place?

Comment: I'm encoding a string in PHP using `base64_encode`. The string is the contents of a rendered phtml file. The receipt prints \x1b etc literally onto the paper. But not if i write \x1b directly into the string on the service side using Visual Studio.

Comment: In that case, can you include the base 64 string being sent for `\x1b\x64\x02`?  With that we might have a [mcve] that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added. Thank you.

Comment: You might have something going wrong on the PHP side.  There is no way the string `\x7` (consisting of one character, the Unicode [`'BELL' (U+0007)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm)) should get base64 encoded to `XHg3`.  Actually, according to https://www.base64decode.org/, `XHg3` decodes to `@"\x7"` - a three-character string literal.  That being said, `Encoding.GetBytes()` and `GetString()` will sometimes replace characters with fallbacks as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441088/3744182).

Comment: I get that `XHg3` is a literal translation, i was originally wondering how i could parse those sequences from a string and decode them to their actual character using C#. But my answer below works for me. Thanks anyway. I probably didn't explain it very well.

Answer (score 0):

So i've found a solution that requires a small amount of change to the template:

On the template side, using PHP, I convert the `\x7` style unicode reference to `&#x7;` and then before i base 64 encode it:

```
$receipt_str = mb_convert_encoding($receipt_str, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

This is working so far. I'm just not sure if there is a better way or if there are limits to this.